# preg_match_callback not matching (regex with backreference)

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace repeated character X with `X{times}` (if X is not `\` or `*`)

```
$mask = "aaaa-dddd";

$mask = preg_replace_callback("/([^\\*])\1+/", function($matches) {

    echo "match!!!"; // never happens

    return $matches[1] . "{" . strlen($matches[0]) . "}";
},  $mask);

echo $mask; // expected: a{4}-d{4}, actual: aaaa-dddd
```

I'm quite confident the regex is correct, but it doesn't seem to match anything at all.

I tried also using `$1` instead of `\1`, but it didn't help.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes. Because within double quotes, `\\` would be treated as an escape sequence not as a regex pattern.

```
$mask = "aaaa-dddd";

$mask = preg_replace_callback('/([^\\*])\1+/', function($matches) {

    echo "match!!!"; // never happens

    return $matches[1] . "{" . strlen($matches[0]) . "}";
},  $mask);

echo $mask;
```

or

```
$mask = preg_replace_callback("/([^\\\\*])\\1+/", function($matches) {

    echo "match!!!"; // never happens

    return $matches[1] . "{" . strlen($matches[0]) . "}";
},  $mask);

echo $mask;
```

Comment: problem is with the quotes if your regex within in double quotes better you need to escape the backslash one more time.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: MightyPork is right, you should have explained in more detail what the problem was.  An OP should never have to ask "okay, but why?" after reading an answer.